# Oracle Pivot & Update

Tags: oracle, merge, sql-update, pivot

I am working on an oracle update sql. Using MERGE function.
I am using a Pivot sql for my source table and updating the destination table columns with the resulting columns from pivot. the issue i am facing is the pivot column names are dynamically generated and i am getting the error of 'invalid identifier'.

Below is the sql sample i am using:

```
    MERGE INTO DEST
USING(
    WITH T AS(
        SELECT COL1,COL2, PIVOTBASECOL,PIVOTMEASURE
        FROM T1
        LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.C1=T2.C1
        )
        SELECT * FROM T PIVOT(
        SUM(PIVOTMEASURE) GAIN FOR PIVOTBASECOL IN('MECH','AL','FAC','OPNS','RMD'))
)SRC ON SRC.COL1=DEST.COL1 AND SRC.COL2=DEST.COL2

WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET DEST.GAIN_MECH=SRC.MECH_GAIN
, DEST.GAIN_AL=SRC.AL_GAIN
, DEST.GAIN_FAC=SRC.FAC_GAIN
, DEST.GAIN_OPNS=SRC.OPNS_GAIN
, DEST.GAIN_RMD=SRC.RMD_GAIN
```

the SRC columns saying 'invalid identifier' because the pivot result column is 'MECH'_GAIN,'AL'_GAIN... 
how could i solve this issue!

Answer (score 1):

Aliases can be defined for each pivot expression:

```
PIVOT (
    COUNT(DUMMY) POSTFIX
    FOR DUMMY IN ('X' ALIAS)
)
```

If you don't use POSTFIX after aggregation function the name of the column with be only ALIAS, otherwise ALIAS_POSTFIX. Pivot column naming is under full control.